# Make production build for web in appflow

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-appflow

I deployed my app in `ionic-appflow`. It created a Web Build, it was build using command `ionic build` and due to which its vendor.js size is **4mb**.

I want to create a production build using command like

```
ionic build --prod or
ionic build --aot
```

How do we do that in `ionic-appflow` ? My main concern is `vendor.js` size.

Comment: I'll take care of this too, today i have learn't a new thing from you that is - not to use code formatting on normal English words. Thanks